# Spring 3 to Spring 5 Migration - URL problems

Tags: java, spring

I recently had to migrate a web app from Spring 3.x to Spring 5.  Most of the migration process was a success until I noticed that any links (like from the menu) to JSP pages are failing with org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound errors. The index page is fine and is pulling in content normally.  Also, links that go to Controller URLs are working. Just that any link going only to a JSP page is failing.  The app-servlet.xml file is pretty much the same as before.  Here's  a snippet:

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />             
</bean>
```

And, also, I am using <mvc:annotation-driven /> and <context:component scan...>.  I have built probably 15 or 20 small to large web apps using Spring 3.x, this is my first spring 5 app (an what a pain!) but never seen this issue before.

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

After hours of research on this problem, I care to admit, I was reading through this article:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Upgrading-to-Spring-Framework-5.x

and under Web Applications/@RequestMapping, I found "If you would like to match to all paths, please use "/**" as the pattern." So I changed my AppController.setupForm(GET) from

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

to

```
@RequestMapping(value="/**", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

and it worked! Hope this helps others...